# How to remove repeated characters from a word using Java and the output word should be meaningful?

Tags: java

I'm facing a problem during preprocessing the data to remove any duplicate characters.Yeah this question was discussed earlier but my question is I want a meaningful word as the output after eliminating all the duplicate characters.Let me make it clear :

Ex:
1.
Input :happpppppy
Output :happy // I dont want hapy as output

2.
Input :hhaappyyyy
Output : happy //i dont want hhaappyy as output

I want to get the output like that which is a dictionary word.

I'm using this code as of now :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class spellcheck1{

public static String charSingleOccurance(String value) {
     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     char last = '\u0000';

    for (char c : value.toCharArray()) {
         if (last == '\u0000' || c != last) {
             result.append(c);
             last = c;
         }
     } 

    return result.toString();
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String output;
output=charSingleOccurance("Happyyyy");
System.out.println(output);
}
}
```

Please correct me to get the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

Since Dictionary class is already deprecated, you can have two options:

1. Connect to an Word Library in the internet such as this http://www.dictionaryapi.com/
2. Download a complete list of words, host it in your local storage, read the file and store it in a Map. You can then check it if the word exists.

---

Use [Dictionary class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) to check if a word exists. As for removing duplicate characters, you want to remove 1 at a time then check if its in the dictionary class, else remove again.

Comment: actually it doesnt give my desired result like a said in the above examples

Comment: Can you give a snippet of how to use Dictionary class in my code?

Comment: Have you read the note in the class you point to: `NOTE: This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the Map interface, rather than extending this class.`

Comment: the project we are working on is confidential so we cannot give the application Url as it is necessary to get the API keys from the link you have mentioned http://www.dictionaryapi.com/ .So your answer will not work out.Gimme some other alternatives.

Comment: You can use option #2.